# PIXI.js - how to use just a small portion of the library?

Tags: pixi.js

I have a very simple PIXI.js setup, with a single filter, sprite and ticker.

I want to only use the relevant parts of the library which is 392kb minified and in this case including a lot of redundant code, given the breadth of the functionality.

How can I do this without something like npm / re-building, or attempting to dig through the source code?

Underscore.js has this [annotated source](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html) which is useful, perhaps there's something along these lines?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tool to customize PIXI.js builds -- https://pixijs.io/customize/